# how to fix expression must have object type c++

Tags: c++

There is a problem with my coding or datatypes. The error says "expression must have pointer-to-object type". I don't know how to fix this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int id, year, dates;

    cout << "Enter the ID number ";
    cin >> id;

    year = id[0] + id[1] + 1900;
    cout << year;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Please, does anybody know you a solution for this?

Comment: What are you expecting from the expressions `id[0]` and `id[1]`?

Comment: I think you have a typo. It should be `using namespace std;` (instead of `namespaces`). But it would be a better idea not to use that at all and just use `std::cout`, etc.

Comment: Do you want to extract the unit's place and the tenth's place from `id` ? `id[0]` & `id[1]` does not make sense for int.

Comment: i tried to get the answer like this

Comment: [You asked the exact same question yesterday.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470708/pointer-to-object-type-c).

Comment: this is a number
932403234
id[0] mean 9 and id[1] mean 3 so then i need to add this two numbers to 1900 there is i need ans

Comment: @ChathuraBuddika Then you use integer division and modulus. How do you want to program without even knowing basic maths (and without a minimal understanding of the language)?

Comment: Why is it that newcomers keep finding Borland console libraries from 1980-something ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some simple math to access the individual digits of your ID:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int id = 189;

    cout << id / 100 % 10 << endl;
    cout << id / 10 % 10 << endl;
    cout << id / 1 % 10 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Yeilds:
1
8
9

Comment: Thank your help dude
i used that and got to continue this and now i'm making my program

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` is an int but you use it like an array:

```
id[0]+id[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `id` as an `int`, but then try to use the `[]` operator on it.  The compiler is "confused" by this and is doing its best to figure out what you mean by using an operator on an `int` - the best it can do it tell you that the expression must be a pointer to an object ( in other words it's telling you it can't use an operator on something of type `int` - instead it should be a pointer or an object).

Comment: How can i do this
pointer or object type
my teacher told me this can use by truncating
Dear i know basics of programming but i don't know how to do this job